# Curl error when used in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, curl, libcurl

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "curl\curl.h"
#include "curl\easy.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init ();
if (curl)
{
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
res = curl_easy_perform (curl);
curl_easy_cleanup (curl);
}
  return 0;
}
```

Running this gives me an error : "The ordinal 3109 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll"

I added the required dlls and libs and still getting this.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Curl has been built against a different version of OpenSSL than the one you have installed - check what version of OpenSSL the version of Curl you are using was built against and use the correct OpenSSL binaries. If that is not possible you could rebuild using the development package of the OpenSSL version you are using.

Comment: I solved it by replacing libeay32.dll in my /windows/syswow64 with the one i got with my curl version.Thank you.